# How to set camera view to fill it's parent view

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, ios8, avcapturesession

I don't know if this problem is something about auto layout or I am doing something wrong.
I have a `UIViewController` and one `UIView` inside of it.
And I am using `AVCaptureSession` to put camera view inside of it.
Problem is that when I camera view loads inside of view it doesn't fill that view so I have gaps on the left and right side.
What I am trying to do is to fill whole `UIView` with camera.
This is my code:

```
...
@IBOutlet weak var camView: UIView!
var previewLayer    : AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer!

override func viewDidLoad() {
...
previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer.layerWithSession(session) as! AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer
        previewLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill
previewLayer.frame = self.camView.layer.bounds
self.camView.layer.addSublayer(previewLayer)
session.startRunning()
```

Comment: Did it work for you?

Comment: No. When I move code to viewdidlayoutsubviews it doesn't work at all. On the view I have uiview and tableciew bellow it. And it seams that autolayout somehow increase uiview height and that is why Camera is not same size like uiview. I don't know how to handle it.

Comment: Please provide me with more code to help diagnose this.

Comment: did you try CGRectMake(0, 0, ParentView.width,ParentView.hight); ? to set frame of cameraView.

Comment: @1110 I'm having the same problem now, how do you solved it? thanks!

Answer (score 18):

You need to conduct the setup after your subviews are layed out. In `viewDidLayoutSubviews`

[image: Add view]

[image: Add outlet]

[image: Add Constraints]

```
-(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
    [self setupAVCapture];
}


- (void)setupAVCapture {
    NSError *error = nil;

    AVCaptureSession *session = [AVCaptureSession new];
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
        [session setSessionPreset:AVCaptureSessionPreset640x480];
    else
        [session setSessionPreset:AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto];

    // Select a video device, make an input
    AVCaptureDevice *device = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
    AVCaptureDeviceInput *deviceInput = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:device error:&error];

    if ([session canAddInput:deviceInput])
        [session addInput:deviceInput];

    AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer *previewLayer = [AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer layerWithSession:session];
        [previewLayer setVideoGravity:AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill];

    previewLayer.frame = self.camView.bounds;
    [self.camView.layer addSublayer:previewLayer];
    [session startRunning];
}
```

What was likely happening to you is that the bounds were not accurately set yet in your `viewDidLoad` as the subviews have yet to be laid out according to their constraints. When you instead setup the frame for the `previewLayer` in `viewDidLayoutSubviews` it will adopt the correct orientation. Be careful though, you will also need to adjust the preview on rotation and what not and modify the code I used. Sorry it isn't in swift, but that shouldn't matter. Just move your instantiation and setup into `viewDidLayoutSubviews`

So for your code, you should do something like this:

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
...
previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer.layerWithSession(session) as! AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer
    previewLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill
previewLayer.frame = self.camView.layer.bounds
self.camView.layer.addSublayer(previewLayer)
session.startRunning()
```

Answer (score 0):

To set `priviewLayer` constraints as like below code so it will occupied whole screen.

```
Leading Space = 0 from mainView
Top Space = 0 from mainView
Bottom Space = 0 from mainView 
Trailing Space = 0 from mainView
```

Hope this help you.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me in **Swift 4.2**

Just set your AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer's instance frame to Parent view's frame like below in viewDidLayoutSubviews() function :

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews(){
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        avCaptureVideoPreviewLayerInstance.frame = self.parentView.bounds
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want your layer to fill the UIView properly, you might as well define constraints for it :

```
self.camView.layer.addSublayer(previewLayer)
self.camView.layer.layoutManager = CAConstraintLayoutManager.layoutManager();
self.camView.layer.addConstraint(CAConstraint.constraintWithAttribute(CAConstraintAttribute.MinX, relativeTo: self.camView.layer, attribute: CAConstraintAttribute.MinX, scale: 1, offset: 0));
self.camView.layer.addConstraint(CAConstraint.constraintWithAttribute(CAConstraintAttribute.MaxX, relativeTo: self.camView.layer, attribute: CAConstraintAttribute.MaxX, scale: 1, offset: 0));
self.camView.layer.addConstraint(CAConstraint.constraintWithAttribute(CAConstraintAttribute.Width, relativeTo: self.camView.layer, attribute: CAConstraintAttribute.Width, scale: 1, offset: 0));
self.camView.layer.addConstraint(CAConstraint.constraintWithAttribute(CAConstraintAttribute.Height, relativeTo: self.camView.layer, attribute: CAConstraintAttribute.Height, scale: 1, offset: 0));
session.startRunning()
```

Answer (score -2):

If you are using autolayout then just do:

1. Set your camera view x=0 and with to screen size
2. Apply leading and trailing  constraint to superView

Hope this will help you.